# Create project from maven archetype via Apache Ivy

Tags: ant, maven-2, ivy, maven-archetype

If you want to create project with a Maven archetype you type

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=... -DarchetypeArtifactId=... \
                       -DarchetypeVersion=... -DgroupId=... -DartifactId=... \
                       -Dversion=...
```

How this line would change if you are using Ivy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ivy is not a drop in replacement for maven, it's a dependency manager for ant.
If you want to use archetypes ivy won't be of any help

Answer (score 1):

Since Ant + Ivy is all about configuration and flexibility, since this combo doesn't rely on conventions, since it doesn't suggest any methodology or structure, what should a *"default"* Ant + Ivy project looks like? Does this question even make sense?

You'll find some template for an empty project (like this [ivy-template](http://code.google.com/p/francisoud-sandbox/source/browse/#svn/ivy-template/trunk)) though.