# Alternatives to Maven Archetypes

Tags: ant, maven, ivy, archetypes

We're currently using Ant with Ivy for build and dependency management, but there's an interest in providing template starter projects like Maven provides using archetypes.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html

However, we don't want to go the Maven route for building and dependency management as Ant/Ivy suits our needs currently.

Are there any alternatives that people use instead of Maven archetypes?

Alternatively, are people just using Maven archetypes in a way that complements their  Ant/Ivy projects?

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423077/create-project-from-maven-archetype-via-apache-ivy) answer your question?

Comment: good question.  I don't know the answer but, as an alternative, if I were in your shoes, I'd just quickly grab maven and use it to create a template project, ditch the pom.xml file and use Ant+Ivy from there.

Answer (score 1):

Use SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) and its project templates support (see [this](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/24/custom-project-templates-in-springsource-tool-suite/) blog for more info)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: 2016-12-13**
*This subproject stands retired/[archived](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-dev/201612.mbox/ajax/%3C000301d25510%2433d37720%249b7a6560%24%40de%3E) as shared on its homepage.*

There is <s>young</s> project which just finished incubating in Apache which tries to provide the missing pieces from Ant+Ivy which exist in the Maven world. It is [EasyAnt](http://ant.apache.org/easyant).

In EasyAnt world, archetypes are called [skeletons](http://ant.apache.org/easyant/history/trunk/howto/skeleton.html).